# Implications of using waitfor delay task in ssis package on scheduled server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, task, delay

I have a question regarding implications of using waitfor delay in an execute sql task on an ssis package.  Here's what's going on:  I have source data tables that due to the amount of data and linked server connection yada yada they are dropped and created every night.  Before my package the utilizes this data runs I have a loop for container.  In this container I have an execute sql task that checks to see my source tables exist and if they do not, it sends me and email via email task, then goes to an execute sql task that has a waitfor delay of 30 mins (before looping and checking for source tables again).  Now I thought I was pretty slick with this design but others on my team are concerned because they do not know enough about this waitfor task.  They are concerned that my package could possibly interfere with theirs, or slow down server, use resources etc....

From my google searches I didn't see anything that actually seemed like it would cause issues.  Can anyone here speak to the implications of using this task?

Comment: If the tables aren't found, you'll get an email telling you table wasn't found and then the package spins for 30 minutes. Is the assumption you'll get to a computer, login and create the missing tables before the next check and email cycle?

Comment: nope, one obvious caveat is that it would never end until the tables exist, and I was not necessarily going to login to fix... My other thought is to add a loop counter and stop task.  Not sure how ssis handles something like that but surely it's possible.  I'm curious how many resources are being used on this package when it's essentially just sitting in idle.  Other than using up a spid that someone else could possibly use, but the task uses 1 thread so how realistic is it that while this is looping it would lock other out? or how realistic is it to say that this would slow down other jobs?

Comment: Will it drag down other jobs, nah. Test for yourself, turn on profiler and kick off an SSIS package that waits N timeunits. But, SSIS isn't made to spin. At one point, I was cautioned about having packages that poll for packages as  memory leaks, blah blah blah <sup>citation needed</sup>.  Instead, if it were me, I'd have a SQL Agent that starts at 8 p.m. and the first thing it does is check to see if the target database is valid. If it's not, it fails. On failure, the job retries 30 minutes later upto N retries. On success, next step is to start the SSIS package proper.

Answer (score 0):

SQL WAITFOR is ideal for this requirement IMO - I've been using it in production SSIS packages for years with no issues.  You can monitor it via SSMS Activity Monitor and see that it doesnt consume any resources.